# Faster function of Logarithm and exponent

Tags: performance, matlab

I have a large matrix A and I need to calculate the value of log(1+exp(A)) (where the calculation must be done for each element of A - yes this this is expected value of the gumbel distribution). After some trial and error, I realized that if A is large enough, then this was one of those cases where loops are actually faster than the vectorization:

```
N=25000*20;
n=15;

draws=50;
speed_test=ones(draws,2);

A=rand(N*S,n);
C1=A; %Allocate Memory
C2=A; %Allocate Memory

for t=1:draws
    tic; C1=log(1+exp(A)); speed_test(t,1)=toc;

    tic;
    for i=1:n
        C2(:,i)=log(1+exp(A(:,i)));
    end
    speed_test(t,2)=toc;

end

mean(speed_test)
```

which yields `mean(speed_test)= 0.1789    0.1689`or about 6% faster. I was wondering if anyone has any other suggestions to speed up this calculation? I've heard that performing function like log and exp in C (i.e. mex) can be much faster.

Comment: There are approximations which certainly are faster than the built-in function.  How accurate do you require your results to be?

Comment: Building on Ben Voigt's comment, you could use Taylor or MacLaurin series up to a certain digit precision.

Comment: I'd have to give it more thought, but off the top of my head I'd say I'd like precision in the range of 10^-6 to 10^-8 at the very least.

Comment: have you tried [`reallog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reallog.html)?

Comment: Also, what is the range of `A`? I assume that it's real-valued? You could also try `single` precision, which is sometimes faster (and sometimes slower overall) and uses half as much memory.

Comment: @Shai Just tried it out, but was slower than what I have now. But, I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: @horchler Thanks, that seems to have helped a bit, with small loss in precision.

Comment: I just looked up the [Gumbel distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution), and I'm confused. `log(1+exp(A))` doesn't look anything like the mean of this distribution.

Comment: @horchler Yes, you are correct. I misspoke in my original message. It's the expected value of the maximum of two random variables, which themselves contain Type 1 Extreme Value distributed Random variables.